# What is the required distance of electrical panel from a door?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, doors, garage

How close can I place a main electrical panel from an interior or exterior door? Is there a difference in distance if the panel is placed on the hinged or non-hinged side, or if it is inward or outward swinging door?
The panel would be located in an attached garage.
I am only seeing 30" x 36" and clear above working space rule for an electrical panel.

Comment: That space needs to be kept clear *at all times* not just when the inspector comes... so it is best positioned in a pathway where you need it clear to get through.

Answer (score 4):

### The door's swing can't infringe on the clear working space

The situation you need to watch for here is where the door's swing infringes on said 30" wide by 36" deep working space around the panel, as that creates a situation where an unfortunate electrician taking measurements on a live panel can get clobbered into the panel by the door in a most shocking fashion.  You'll also want to make sure that the panel's own door, if present (as some small panels lack one), can open 90° while the door is fully open, as not being able to open that door 90° is also a Code violation (110.26(A)(2)).

Comment: So if the panel is on the none hinged side of the door, then it can butt up against the door frame?

Comment: @WhoShock -- no, not quite -- you don't want the door to clobber an electrician working on it, even if it won't necessarily cause them to faceplant into a live panel

Comment: Makes sense to not clobber the electrician. That said, it's residential so foot traffic will not be high. As long as it is code, it should be ok right?

Comment: @WhoShock -- yeah, as long as the door doesn't infringe on the Code required working clearance (which does *not* need to be centered on the panel, FYI!), you're cool